# Identifying DGN Spatial Reference for CAD to Geodatabase

Tags: coordinate-system, cad, dgn

I received several DGN files that I need to convert into geodatabase format.
I do not have the spatial reference of the DGN file and I don't have a way to request that from the creator.
When I run the CAD to Geodatabase tool in ArcGIS Pro my results end up in neighboring states as oppose to the where they should be located - downtown Denver, CO.
I couldn't find a similar question in this site aside from missing layers in the result and general functionality of the CAD to Geodatabase tool. Also, I searched the web for tools that can reverse engineer a DGN file and find what is the spatial reference, but with no luck.

If I don't have a DGN's file spatial reference, how do I convert it to GIS format to show in the correct spatial location?

Answer (score 0):

Add the data to a blank and new map project (a map with no spatial reference defined).  Zoom to that data.  Get some coordinates from the data in a place that is identifiable to you like a road intersection, a known building, or a parcel.  [Use this site](http://projfinder.com/) and zoom to that area you have identified.  Add the coordinates.